# MySQL Filter Records Set Using DD-MM-YYYY Date Format

Tags: mysql, date, filter, format

I'm a bit confused on how to filter records by date formats.

I have date column of date(yyyy-mm-dd) data type in date table.

Ex:

```
date
-----
2017-01-29
2017-01-30
```

I'm want to change the format (dd-mm-yyyy). I'm using this code

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') as date
FROM
    dim_date;

date
-----
29-01-2017
30-01-2017
```

I want to filter the records with the(dd-mm-yyyy) format. So I tried this code.

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') date
FROM
    dim_date
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '20-04-2015' AND '06-09-2017';
```

Results
**Nothing**

But if I try to filter with the original format (yyyy-mm-dd) It Works.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y') date
FROM dim_date
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2015-04-20' AND '2017-01-07';
```

Why is this weird behavior in Mysql? Am I missing something here?

I also tried with this format `DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%c-%Y')` , `DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%l-%Y')` & `DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%e-%l-%Y')` 
No happy face, Please let me known.

Thanks

Max

Comment: i don't see difference between the two query  ..  .. please explain better

Comment: `Date_format` will give you a string. And if you compare your values as a string, there is no character that is `>=2`  and `<=0` (which is what `between '2' and '0'` will be looking for). Why do you want to use it that way? You can just convert your input to a valid date and compare valid dates. It will also allow you to use indexes. And, well, it will actually filter as you want it to work.

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated the query. please check now. Sorry, I am confused with the date formats for now.

Answer (score 0):

with your query you convert the date in string and then you are comparing values using between in wrong order ('20' > '06'   )  so don't work.
Between require first the min value and second the max value.

If you are working with date you  sould  convert the string date
so the where  between work correcly and avoid the string behavior is filter

```
SELECT date 
FROM dim_date
WHERE date   BETWEEN str_to_dat('20-04-2015', '%d-%m-%Y') 
            AND str_to_date('06-09-2017', '%d-%,-%Y');
```

Comment: explain better you comment  .. please

Comment: your update versione work   .. because the string is coherent with between  rules .but the problem   .. I  suggest as in my answer  the use of date for a better comparision  ..  so instead that convert a date in string is right convert a string in date  .. (or use the default strinf format for date)